# Abstract Algebra: Proof Verification Permutations on a Finite Set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $A$ be a finite set and $B$ be a subset of $A$. Let $G$ be the subset of $S_A$ consisting of all permutations $f$ of $A$ such that $f(x)∈B$ for every $x∈B$. Prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_A$.

My attempt-

Let $f,g∈G$.

Then for all $x∈B$, $f(x)∈B$ and $g(x)∈B$.

This implies that $f(g(x))∈B$. Thus, $G$ is closed.

Let $f∈G$

Let the elements of $B$ be $x_1,x_2,.....x_n$. Any distinct element $x_i$ of $B$ can be written as a distinct $f(x_j)$ where $x_j∈B$.

$f^{-1}(f(x_j))$ = $x_j$ by the definition of the inverse function.

We can write $f(x_j)$ as $x_i$ for some $x_i∈B$.

$f^{-1}(x_i))$ = $x_j$

Through this, we conclude that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_A$

Comment: This is an expression of the fact that $S_B \times S_{A\setminus B}$ can be embedded in $S_A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems fine, but it'd be better if you explained why for all $x_i$, there exists $x_j\in B$ so that $f(x_j)=x_i$. Why does $x_j$ have to live in $B$? It's true, but why? All you know at the outset is that there exists $x_j\in A$ with that property since $f\in S_A$, so $f$ is surjective.

Here's (maybe) a simpler way to go. Use the [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Clearly $1_{S_A}\in G$, so $G\neq \varnothing$. Let $f,g\in G$ and $x_i\in B$. The set $\{g(x_j)\}_{j=1}^n$ is a collection of $|B|=n$ distinct elements of $B$ since $x_j\neq x_k\implies g(x_j)\neq g(x_k)$ since $g$ is injective. Hence there exists $x_j\in B$ so that $g(x_j) = x_i$. So $g^{-1}(x_i) = x_j\in B$, and hence $f(g^{-1}(x_i))\in B$. So $fg^{-1}\in G$ and therefore by the subgroup test, $G$ is a group.

Comment: Do I have to state that $f$ is bijective from $B$ to $B$ even though It's given that it is a permutation of $B$?

Comment: It's not given that $f$ is a permutation of $B$. It's only given that $f$ is a permutation of $A$, and if $f\in G$ you must argue why $f$ is a permutation of $B$.

Comment: It's pretty easy to prove that $f$ is injective from $B$ to $B$ since if there are some distinct elements $x$ and $y$ for which $f(x)$ = $f(y)$ then $f$ would no longer be injective over $A$. Since $B$ is finite, we can also conclude that $f$ is surjective from $B$ to $B$. Is this enough?

Comment: That's correct. Sure it's easy to prove, but it's not given. That fact is at the heart of the proof. That's essentially what I proved in my answer when I considered the set $\{g(x_j)\}_{j=1}^n$.

Comment: @ArjunNigam If my answer helped, feel free to make my response the “accepted answer” by clicking the arrow next to my response, and by giving me an upvote, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Here's a different proof of the fact that $f\in G\implies f^{-1}\in G$. Take $f\in G$ and suppose that $f^{-1}\notin G$. Then there's a $b\in B$ such that $f^{-1}(b)\notin B$. If you restrict $f$ to $\{f^{-1}(b)\}\cup B$, then you have an injective function from a set with $\#B+1$ elements into a set with $\#B$ elements, which is impossible.